# PySide Signal with Argument

Tags: python, pyside, signals-slots, qgroupbox

`QGroupBox` has the signal `clicked` which has an optional `checked` parameter. Suppose I'm trying to connect a slot to it inside of some class like so: `box.clicked.connect(self.func)`, so the declaration of the slot must be `def func(self, checked)`, but `func` is being called with only one argument. How do I get the desired behaviour of `func` being called with both self and the optional `checked` arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of signals with optional default parameters differs between PyQt and PySide. In PyQt, the default parameter is *always* sent, but in PySide you have to explicitly request it:

```
    box.clicked[bool].connect(self.func)
```

This is a much better design choice, I would say, as the PyQt behaviour can often lead to bugs if you forget that a default value will be sent even though you didn't ask for it. A case of explicit being better than implicit...